# Present View Controller after picking image from gallery

Tags: ios, swift

I want to present a viewcontroller after i pick an image from gallery i am getting this Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Can anyone help regarding this

my code is

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String: Any]) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        if (info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage) != nil {
            print(info)
            if let manageDocumentController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ManageDocumentVC")
                as? ManageDocumentVC {
                let navController = SMNavigationController(rootViewController: manageDocumentController)
                self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to set the code of presenting view controller in completion closure , so you need to do that  dismiss(animated: true, completion: {// code of presenting view controller })

Comment: instead of this self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil) replace navController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: @Hosnny tried this but getting same issue

Comment: @Joshnagoud Please can show your code ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to present to viewController, you should use this code:

```
if let manageDocumentController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ManageDocumentVC") as? ManageDocumentVC {
   self.present(manageDocumentController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

If you viewController has NavigationController, you should use next code:

```
if let navController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "nameOfNavigationControllerIdentifier") {
   self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```